# How to remove deleted page from google indexing

Tags: blogger, google-cache

I had a blogger site and deleted it a month ago. But it is still appearing in Google result index , and the past content is also visible from cached option of Google search results. I have tried to remove in site site : https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals , but still it is appearing in results. Is there any way that i could remove the page or the cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will simply take time. If the site has been removed and you have removed it from Google Webmaster Tools, then there is nothing else you can do short of one option.

If there were not too many pages on your blogger site, you can open Google Webmaster Tools > Google Index > Remove URLs. I assume there is a limit, but I cannot find it.

Search engines are notoriously slow. It can take months before a site is removed. However, if a high number of 404 errors exist for a particular site, Google will sample the site to see if the site has been removed. It will drop in the SERPs due to a high number of errors while Google determines that a site does in fact exist or not. Not knowing blogger, I would assume that this would go faster if the sub-domain does not exist. If the sub-domain does not exist, then it may take less time since the site domain name will no longer resolve. If the sub-domain still exist, then it may take a bit longer.

As with anything dealing with search, you just have to be patient.

Answer (score 1):

I think they will not take more than 30 days to remove blogger post/page, In generally, When you create any blog on Blogger, then they will create account automatically in GWT(Google webmaster Tools), If you already submit sitemap, then you will get continuously notice about your blog. So when you delete your blog, they will give you errors on GWT.

Their service is better than better, When you delete your blog, they will give you chance to recover within 90 days, Then they will permanently delete your blog, also they de-indexed your all links automatically in 90 days.

If you want result urgently, Then first undelete your blog, Go to setting << basic << Privacy, and select no option.then again use GWT and request for URL removals.